# Autodesk forge - accessing projects

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I've been trying to get my projects using the Autodesk API by following the tutorial in the docs (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/), but after calling `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs`, I get the following response:

```json
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs"
        }
    },
    "data": [],
    "meta": {
        "warnings": [
            {
                "Id": null,
                "HttpStatusCode": "404",
                "ErrorCode": "BIM360DM_ERROR",
                "Title": "Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM US.",
                "Detail": "The requested object could not be located.",
                "AboutLink": null,
                "Source": null,
                "meta": null
            },
            {
                "Id": null,
                "HttpStatusCode": "403",
                "ErrorCode": "BIM360DM_ERROR",
                "Title": "Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM EMEA.",
                "Detail": "You don't have permission to access this API",
                "AboutLink": null,
                "Source": null,
                "meta": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Steps I followed in the tutorial:

- I created account
- I sent an email to `bim360appsactivations@autodesk.com` (got a response that my account was changed to the developer account)
- I connected my app to BIM 360 Account in "Add Custom Integration"

Did I forget some important step while setting this up?
Thanks

Comment: I do not see anything missed in your steps. One question I can think of is: when you connected app by [Add Custom Integration]',  did you see the option  (Document Management) as tutorial shows, or only [Administrator Management]? We did have one issue with some BIM360 accounts. Without that option, the API will throw the error like that because it has not enabled you to access hubs, projects etc..

Comment: I can see both 'BIM 360 Account Administration' and 'Document management'

Comment: could you send us aps.help@autodesk.com with your BIM account id and client  id of  APS application? We will check backend log if it tells any clue.

Comment: We have this collection of troubleshoot checklists.  Could you go through?  
https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2018/05/31/troubleshooting-tips-for-accessing-bim-360-docs-and-account-admin/

Comment: Thanks for the checklist, I've actually did all of the points there, so I sent an email to aps.help@autodesk.com